# Generating PDF files using pdfkit in nodejs and sql server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, pdfkit

I'm trying to generate pdf file using pdfkit in nodejs, and using sql server as my database. The problem is that when i'm generating pdf with static data(sample data defining in code) the pdf is generating with record, but when im trying to import data from sql server and generating pdf its not reading the table columns and giving error: Data not found TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
My code:

```
async function createPdf(mob, path) {

   try{
     let  pool = await  sql.connect(config);
     mob = await  pool.request()
     .input('input_parameter', sql.VarChar, mob)
     .query("SELECT * from Users where Mobile = @input_parameter");


     
     let doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4", margin: 50 });

     generateHeader(doc);
     generateCustomerInformation(doc, mob);
     generateHeading(doc);

     generateFooter(doc);

     doc.end();
     doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));

}
   catch (error){
     console.log("Data not found", error);
   }
```

My generate customer design and data calling

```
function generateCustomerInformation(doc, mob) {
  doc
    .fillColor("#444444")
    .fontSize(14)
    .text("Personal Information:", 50, 160);

  generateHr(doc, 185);

  const customerInformationTop = 200;

  doc
    .fontSize(10)
    .font("Helvetica")
    .text(formatDate(new Date()), 50, customerInformationTop + 45)

    .font("Helvetica-Bold")
    .text(mob.Users.Name, 50, customerInformationTop)
    .font("Helvetica")
    .text(mob.Users.Address, 50, customerInformationTop + 15)
    .text(
      mob.Users.City+
        ", " +
        mob.Users.Country,
      50,
      customerInformationTop + 30
    )
    .text(mob.Users.ZakatStatus, 50, customerInformationTop + 60)
    .moveDown();
}
```

Method behind i want to create pdf:

```
router.route('/user/AccountStatement/:mobile').get((request, response) => {

  pdf.createPdf("invoice.pdf")
  response.json("Success!");
})
```

How i can manipulate data and call data from sql if my technique is wrong is there any other way ?

Comment: What is the value of `mob.Users`? The `query()` function returns a Record Sets collection, so your data is probably inside `mob.recordset[0]`.

Comment: Yes i know and when i'm printing this: console.log(mob.recordset[0].Name); it is giving me NAME that is stored in database, but when im writing it in my generateCustomerInformation function its not reading record

Comment: How are `mob.Users` and `mob.recordset[0]` connected?